# Return field in a Graphql query as a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I have a Graphql query where I want to return particular fields as a list. Is there a way that I can do this? For example:

Here is my typedef:

```
type Identity{
    First:String,
    Last:String,
    Age:String
    }
```

Here is my type query

```
getIdentityDetails:[Identity]
```

Here is my resolvers

```
getIdentityDetails: async () =>{
    try {
        const identity = await Identity_Table.findAll();
        return identity;
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
},
```

Now, here is how I query it

```
{getIdentityDetails
   {
    First
    Last
    Age
   }
}
```

What I want is to retrieve each field as a list in my query result so for the first I want it to come out as `["john"]` not "john".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A list of `Identity` objects and a list of strings is entirely different, so what you're describing doesn't really make sense. You need to define a new field with a different type to get an array of first names.

Comment: loganfsmyth ok thank you i thought there was a way that i did not know about